# Is there any visual editor that create and edit graphics (images, diagrams, shapes) and save it as "code/script"?

Tags: javascript, visualization, graphviz, graph-visualization, image-editing

I am looking for a visual editor that can create and edit graphs and diagrams and can save the result as (or read from) some code file (JavaScript, Python...).

Does anyone know if such thing exists? Even the simplest one will do.

Thank you.

Comment: https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/svg-edit-2.8.1/svg-editor.html

Comment: Could you add context. For what purpose you need it saved as script? Will SVGs work? If not why not?